# Broken pipe (Java, Apache Mina)

Tags: java, apache-mina

I have a problem using Apache Mina with flash (client/server game).

When user closes his browser process via task manager (or Flash player in IDE), server throws infinitely exceptions "Java.io.BrokenPipe".

Changing O/S TCP/IP settings (keep-alive) didn't work.

Comment: Keepalive has nothing to do with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The server is repeatedly try to write to the socket and ignoring the broken pipe exception.  It should close its end of the socket in response to the exception.

Answer (score 1):

when you receive the broken pipe exception in your IoHandler, you need to close the session. The remote peer connection is dead.